# How do I grab state information from custom header button component in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm new to React. I'm having a tough time trying to change how a screen looks depending on what value I select inside a dialog/modal that pops up when I press the header button using a Stack Navigator.

This is a gif of what it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/Yw2jbHu.gifv

This is what my Stack Navigation looks like:

```
const HistoryStack = () =>{
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:true,headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#21252B',shadowColor: '#333842'},headerTintColor:"#528bff",headerTitleAlign: 'center'  }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Logging" options={({ navigation, route })=> ({headerTitle: props => <SwitchWorkoutButton/>})}component={Logging} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

As you can see I made the header title my own custom button component. I added a currentWorkout state variable to the component that gets set whenever a value selected in the dialog.

This is what the header button looks like:

```
const SwitchWorkoutButton = () =>{
    const  [showDialog,setShowDialog] = useState(false)
    const [currentWorkout,setCurrentWorkout] = useState('A')

    const renderDialog = (showDialog) =>{
        return (<Dialog migrate visible={showDialog} useSafeArea bottom onDismiss={setShowDialog(false)}>test</Dialog>)
    }

    const closeDialog = () =>{
        setShowDialog(false)
    }

    const openDialog = () =>{
        setShowDialog(true)
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Chip label ="Workout A" 
            iconStyle={{margin: 4,tintColor:'#528bff',width:11,height:6}}  
            rightIconSource={require('../assets/chevronDown.png')}  
            labelStyle={{color: Colors.white,fontSize:13}}
            containerStyle={{borderColor: "#2D2E33", backgroundColor: "#2D2E33", marginLeft: Spacings.s3,padding:2.5,width:115}}
            onPress={() =>{ console.log('pressed',showDialog)
                setShowDialog(true)
                console.log('pressed',showDialog)
            }}/>

                <Dialog migrate height={150} containerStyle={styles.roundedDialog} panDirection={PanningProvider.Directions.UP} visible={showDialog} onDismiss={closeDialog} useSafeArea top>
                    
                        <View style ={{backgroundColor:'#2d2e33',borderBottomColor:'#929497',borderBottomWidth:.2,alignItems:'center',}}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:20,marginVertical:10,color:'#929497'}}>Switch Workout</Text>
                        </View>   

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setCurrentWorkout('B')}}>
                            <View style ={{paddingLeft:20,marginVertical:5,marginTop:10}}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'#929497',}}>Workout B</Text>
                            </View> 
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{setCurrentWorkout('C')}}>
                            <View style ={{paddingLeft:20,marginVertical:5}}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'#929497'}}>Workout C</Text>
                            </View>   
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                </Dialog>               
        </View>
    );
}
```

And this is the page where the content is displayed through my WorkoutSet component that gets passed a prop that I will use to display the correct data.

```
const Logging = ({navigation}) =>{
    const [selectedIndex,setSelectedIndex] = useState(0)
    

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'#21252B'}}>

         <View style={{ flex:3}} >
          <WorkoutSet id={'A'}/>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

My question is how do I grab the value I selected in the dialog to do that. I've read through https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/ but their use case is different than mine.

Comment: You could store that value in a context to make it accessible where you need it